# Convert GergorianCalendar date into a custom date format in Freemarker

Tags: java, freemarker

I have a GergorianCalendar date in format `2018-04-30T00:00:00.000+05:30`. I need to change its time zone and convert it into format `01/07/2018 9:55 AM ET`. How to accomplish this in freemarker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First where FreeMarker is configured (with its Java API or via a `java.util.Properties` usually), set the `time_zone` configuration setting to `EST` (or set the default time zone of Java to that) and the `datetime_format` configuration setting to `"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a z"`. (You can also set them in the template like `<#setting time_zone="EST">`, but it's generally a bad practice.)

Then, if you can, convert that `String` to `java.util.Date` before calling FreeMarker, so that it's already a `Date` in the data-model. But if you can't, you can do that in the template as well:

```
${d?datetime.iso}
```

where ISO refers to the ISO 8601:2004 format, which the string you show uses.